# Matrix multiplication with transpose

Tags: matrices

This is a question from a Machine Learning quiz :

[image]

How I arrived at this answer :

u transpose = [4 -4 3]

```
So :  [4 -4 3] * 4
                 2
                 4

= 16 + -8 + 12
= 20
```

What mistake have I made in my calculation ?

Comment: You copied the wrong number in the 3rd component of $u$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've forgotten a minus sign in the vector u.

Answer (score 0):

Check your math.

$$ (4)*(4) + (-4)*(2) + (-3)*(4) = \ldots $$